# What's the reason to make a conditional without a result?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code:

```
navigation.on('click', '.main-nav-item', function (e) {
    var clickedNavItem = $j(this),
        className = clickedNavItem.data('class'),
        midNavItem = $j('.' + className, midNavigation);

    midNavItem.length > 0 && e.preventDefault();
});
```

I try to understand the purpose of the last row:

```
midNavItem.length > 0 && e.preventDefault();
```

It seems to stop the click if midNavItem.Length > 0, but I don't under stand the syntax of this. It ought to be_

```
if(midNavItem.length > 0) { e.preventDefault() };
```

Not two conditionals.

Why would you write it like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How it works

It's known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You are correct – it is another way of writing the `if` statement you suggested:

```
if (midNavItem.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

It works because [`&&` won't execute the second operand unless the first is truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

#### Why it is used

The rationale for using it is typically to make for neater code. This, of course, is subjective. There are probably people who say it is always better to explicitly use the `if` syntax – but you will also find a number of people / popular libraries using the shorthand extensively.

Comment: @Cerbrus Quote from OP: `I don't under stand the syntax of this`. But you are correct in that I only answered that half of the question – edited to answer the second half ('why').

Answer (score 3):

It's shorter.

Although in this case that "shortness" is lost by the large amounts of whitespace.

This is the kind of optimisation that should *only* be done by a minifying program, *not* manually, because it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Is this not subjective? As I understand it many people (and popular libraries) argue that it makes the code *more* readable. I agree that optimising for shortness is generally a very bad thing to do – but I feel there's a little more to this one that just shortness...